# Python: How can I use arguments in a function used as argument itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do something that I don't know if it's very ugly...

I'm trying to do a little webscraping and I pretend to generalize a function to extract the correct class.

The code is:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def has_label_key(tag):
     print(tag)
     return tag.has_attr("data-acc") and tag["data-acc"]=="WOTD"

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("http://dle.rae.es/srv/search",data={"":"diccionario"}
bs(r.text).find_all(has_label_key)[0].id.text
```

What I pretend to do is:

```
def has_label_key(tag,**kwargs):
    print(tag)
    return tag.has_attr(kwargs["label"]) and tag[kwargs["label"]]==key

bs(r.text).find_all(has_label_key(label="data-acc",key="WOTD"}))[0].i.text
```

The first difference I can see between the first function and second is, for example, in the first case, tag is a bs object which I can fragment and search inside. In the second case, is an empty tuple

Is there any way to pass arguments to the function **has_label_key** and use it inside the function **has_attr()**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you're passing a *function* to `find_all`:

```
bs(r.text).find_all(has_label_key)[0].id.text
```

In the second case, however, you're trying to call the function and passing its *result* to `find_all`:

```
bs(r.text).find_all(has_label_key(label="data-acc",key="WOTD"}))[0].i.text
```

(Actually calling the function doesn't work, because it's missing the `tag` argument.)

One way to fix it is to use a lambda as the argument, which is like defining a new function inline:

```
bs(r.text).find_all(lambda tag: has_label_key(tag, label="data-acc",key="WOTD"}))[0].i.text
```

Another way is to define a function inside `has_label_key` which captures the arguments of the outer function, and then return that inner function:

```
def has_label_key(label, key):
    def inner(tag):
        print(tag)
        return tag.has_attr(label) and tag[label]==key
    return inner

bs(r.text).find_all(has_label_key(label="data-acc",key="WOTD"}))[0].i.text
```

P.S. You can also write `return tag.get(label) == key`. The `get` function returns `None` if the attribute doesn't exist, instead of raising an exception.